# Buffer switcher plugin for vim

Tags: vim, buffer, vim-plugin

I'm looking for a buffer switcher plugin for vim. It's shown in the following screenshot. Can anyone tell me what it is and how to get it?

[image: screenshot of vim with arrow indicating bold, differently colored top tab]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is actually not a plugin at all. It's a [native vim tab](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/tabpage.html). You can create a new tab via `:tabnew`.

Comment: You are using the Windows version of VIM, so it can use "real" tab widgets.  This screenshot is of a terminal emulator running VIM, so it has to emulate any graphical controls with carefully arranged characters on screen.